# IndexedDB shim: delete operation crashes in Android

Tags: android, cordova, indexeddb, polyfills, shim

**Edit: for some reason I cannot even begin to understand, the code is now working!** I have no clue about why this is the case.

I am using the [IndexedDB shim](https://github.com/axemclion/IndexedDBShim/blob/master/dist/IndexedDBShim.js) in a PhoneGap project. I've written some code that seems to work flawlessly in Chrome but when I try to execute the same code in both Android 4.0 and 4.2, it crashes. Here's the culprit:

```
deleteAll : function(table) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var dbOpenPromise = $.indexedDB(DB_NAME, {"version" : DB_VERSION});

    dbOpenPromise.done(function(db, event){
        var objectStore = $.indexedDB(DB_NAME).objectStore(table);
        var promise = objectStore.clear();
        promise.done(function(result, event){
            deferred.resolve();
        });
        promise.fail(function(error, event) {
            deferred.reject();
        });
    });

    dbOpenPromise.fail(function(db, event) {
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
},
```

When I try to execute that (which can happen in an already empty table sometimes), the polyfill crashes. I tracked the issue down to this line:

```
function throwDOMException(name, message, error) {
    var e = new DOMException.prototype.constructor(0, message);
```

Android kept complaining about an illegal constructor, so I changed it to this:

```
function throwDOMException(name, message, error) {
    var e = new DOMException.constructor(0, message);
```

With this, it would now cast the exception unhindered. The exception was being thrown in lines 1049 and 1057:

```
if (value) {
    try {
        var primaryKey = eval("value['" + props.keyPath + "']");
        if (!primaryKey) {
            if (props.autoInc === "true") {
                getNextAutoIncKey();
            }
            else {
                // here
                idbModules.util.throwDOMException(0, "Data Error - Could not eval key from keyPath");
            }
        }
        else {
            callback(primaryKey);
        }
    } 
    catch (e) {
        // and here
        idbModules.util.throwDOMException(0, "Data Error - Could not eval key from keyPath", e);
    }
}
```

What can be causing this crash? Am I doing something wrong?

(Further information, just in case it's helpful: I'm not doing anything in particular to initialize the shim, other than loading it right after I load the PhoneGap main file and before loading all my application scripts. Do I need to do something special?)

Comment: This is really weird, __deriveKey is only called from the IDBObjectStore.add and IDBObjectStore.put methods. Are you sure the delete is causing this? Or is there some other running operation?

Comment: Hi. I need to apologize but it turns out that the code is working flawlessly now and I have absolutely no idea why. It's working perfectly both in my PC and the Android devices. In any case, thanks again for your help!